# Java: int[] array vs int array[]

Tags: java, arrays, performance, definition

Is there a difference between

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

and

```
int array[] = new int[10];
```

?

Both do work, and the result is exactly the same. Which one is quicker or better? Is there a style guide which recommends one?

Comment: Official recommendation: the second notation is "Yechh": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2-210

Comment: @assylias I think the yechhh referred to doing int[] a[], instead of int[][] a. It's related, but not quite the same a what OP was asking about.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Both are equivalent. Take a look at the following:

```
int[] array;

// is equivalent to

int array[];
```

```
int var, array[];

// is equivalent to

int var;
int[] array;
```

```
int[] array1, array2[];

// is equivalent to

int[] array1;
int[][] array2;
```

```
public static int[] getArray()
{
    // ..
}

// is equivalent to

public static int getArray()[]
{
    // ..
}
```

Comment: I personally think the flexibility using `[]` can be confusing and should be more consistent (and strict).

Answer (score 9):

From JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html#10.2

Here are examples of declarations of array variables that do not create arrays:

```
int[ ] ai;          // array of int
short[ ][ ] as;         // array of array of short
Object[ ]   ao,     // array of Object
        otherAo;    // array of Object
Collection<?>[ ] ca;        // array of Collection of unknown type
short       s,      // scalar short 
        aas[ ][ ];  // array of array of short
```

Here are some examples of declarations of array variables that create array objects:

```
Exception ae[ ] = new Exception[3]; 
Object aao[ ][ ] = new Exception[2][3];
int[ ] factorial = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040 };
char ac[ ] = { 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ',
                 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g' }; 
String[ ] aas = { "array", "of", "String", };
```

**The [ ] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both**, as in this example:

```
byte[ ] rowvector, colvector, matrix[ ];
```

**This declaration is equivalent to:**

```
byte rowvector[ ], colvector[ ], matrix[ ][ ];
```

Comment: The latest version of the JLS is clearer on the subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2-210

Answer (score 8):

They are both basically same, there is no difference in performance of any sort, the recommended one however is the first case as it is more readable.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

FROM [**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.

Comment: It would be better if you extend the answer. Who recommends that? For me the second is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Both are the same.
I usually use `int[] array = new int[10];`, because of better (contiguous) readability of the type `int[]`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference. But I prefer using `int[] array` as it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between these two declarations, and both have the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is virtually no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples, you are assigning a `new int[10]` to a reference variable.

Assigning to a reference variable either way will be equal in performance.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

The notation above is considered best practice for readability.

Cheers