# why one class of same package can't access another?

Tags: java, package

```
package MyPack;
class Balance
{
    String name;
    protected double bal;
    Balance(String n, double b)
    {
        name=n;
        bal=b;
    }
    void show()
    {
        if(bal<0)
        System.out.print("--> ");
        System.out.println(name+": $" +bal);
    }
}
```

class : AccountBalance

```
package MyPack;
class AccountBalance
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Balance current[]=new Balance[3];
        current[0]=new Balance("K. J. Fielding", 123.23);
        current[1]=new Balance("will Tell", 157.02);
        current[2]=new Balance("Tom Jackson", -12.33);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) current[i].show();
    }
}
```

I have put both these classes in Balance.java  and  AccountBalance.java . both files are in E:/programs/MyPack . Balance.java compiles without error But when I compile AccountBalance.java it gives error : cannot find symbol "Balance".

I'm unable to figure out why when both classes are declared in same package?

I'm compiling from MyPack using
javac Balance.java
javac AccountBalance.java

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559749/java-int-array-vs-int-array

Comment: How do you compile them? Show us your `javac` commands.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - you provided a link that agreed with him

Comment: @brso05 - Don't need to import if they are in the same location

Comment: It complied properly from my end. I copied your code exactly

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: Is it accessible if you use the fully qualified name? `MyPack.Balance current[] = new MyPack.Balance[3]`

Comment: using Eclipse, this compiles just fine, like @CharlesWhitfield mentioned. Might be how you're trying to compile them

Comment: I'm compiling from MyPack using
javac Balance.java
javac AccountBalance.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're issuing your `javac` command from some folder other than `E:/programs`, you'll need to specify a `-cp` option including the location that includes your `Balance` class.

This is because [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) uses the current directory if the option isn't specified

> If neither `CLASSPATH`, `-cp` nor `-classpath` is specified, the user class
>   path consists of the current directory.

So if you did, for example,

```
E:/> javac programs/MyPack/AccountBalance.java
```

then the `Balance` class will not be in the classpath and the compiler will give you the error you see.

In that case, you'll need to specify an explicit location for your classpath. For example

```
E:/> javac -cp programs programs/MyPack/AccountBalance.java
```

Since `Balance` is in package `MyPack` which is at the root of `/E/programs`, the compiler finds it and can use it.

---

Use an IDE.

Comment: If you are in `E:/programs/MyPack` you should also specify cp... `E:/programs` is OK.

Comment: You have to compile Balance.java from E:/programs/MyPack
using : javac Balance. java

now you compile from E:/programs/MyPack
using : javac -cp E:/programs AccountBalance.java
or,
    javac -classpath E:/programs AccountBalance.java


if you compile from E:/programs then use
    javac E:/programs/MyPack/AccountBalance.java

nothing else works..

Comment: @abhi It doesn't matter whete you compile it from. What matters is that the classpath is correct and contains the required classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `javac` the reason is that you compile them one by one (first `Balance` then `AccountBalance`) and you are not in the parent folder of `MyPack`. If you are really doing so, then please use the `-cp` option of `javac` to point where is the already compiled `Balance.class`. For example:

```
..\so\src\MyPack>javac Balance.java

..\so\src\MyPack>javac -cp ../. AccountBalance.java
```

Alternatively compule them both, e.g:

```
..\so\src\MyPack>javac *.java
```

Comment: No it isn't. If the compiler is used correctly it can compile them one by one in either order. He could also use the `-sourcepath` option, or best of all he could just put himself into the correct working directory before issuing the command, that is to say the directory containing the `MyPack` directory.